# Fetching dynamic id and url from image with JS

Tags: fancybox

I'm implementing a fancybox into my project and I'm writing a script to automatically wrap an anchor around the images with the url to the image and a "data-fancybox" attribute to let the fancybox script do its thing. However, I'm only getting the url to the very first image, since they all share the same class. There is a dynamic figure id that seems to be the one to get.

My question is - how do I use this figure id to fetch the appropriate img src?

The html is like this:

```
    <figure id="XXXXXXX">
    <div>

    <img src="image.jpg" />

    </div>
    </figure>

... other stuff ...

    <figure id="YYYYYYY">
    <div>

    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    </figure>
```

My code right now is as follows (which works, but only returns the first image url):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var src = $("figure img").attr("src");
        var a = $("<a/>").attr( { href:src , "data-fancybox":"" } );
        $("figure img").wrap(a);
});
```

I know I can use

```
var id = $("figure").attr("id");
```

to get the id I need, but I'm pretty new to coding so I'm not sure how I implement this and use it to get the correct url. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you rephrase your comment? I could not understand your issue at all. Sounds like you are mixing multiple questions in one, but it just does not make sense in the end.

Comment: Sure, thanks for answering! Edited for clarification. My question is - how can do I fetch and use the "figure id" here to fetch the appropriate "img src"?

Comment: Try using https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ to iterate your objects and then do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make your images clickable, then you can do smth like this:

```
$('figure img').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css({cursor: 'pointer'}).attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery').attr('data-src', this.src);
});
```

DEMO - https://jsfiddle.net/1jznsL7x/

Tip: There is no need to create anchor elements, you can add `data-fancybox` and `data-src` attributes to any element and it will work automagically.